# Title heading for bibliography and list of figures overlapped with Header

Tags: biblatex

I am currently having a problem trying to fix the issue where my section title heading are overlapped with the header of my document. See below image

[image]

[image]

The thing is this only occurs for  (Bibliography, List of Figures, List of tables etc.) but does not affect my chapter heading section. I've been trying to find a fix for this but I cant for the life of me figure it out.

For instance, this one is fine!

[image]

The only part of the code that deals with the bibliography is this

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------
% BIBLIOGRAPHY (DATABASE)
% -------------------------------------------------------------
\printbibliography
```

I tried looking if there is any argument for `\printbibliography` that adds vertical spacing from the top page margin, but I could not find anything. Guidance on how I can solve this will be much appreciated!

I've tried adding vspace and try to push it further down but nothing is working :(

Edit: How do I fix the issue of the section title overlapping with my header?

Here is a MWE that should work

```
\documentclass[11pt,                                          % Main text font size
%               a4paper,                                       % Paper size
               %openright,                                     % Chapters start on odd pages (right)
               twoside]{report}                               % Print two-sided, LaTeX 'report' template

\usepackage[a4paper,                                          % Paper size
            top = 20mm,                                       % Top margin
            bottom = 20mm,                                    % Bottom margin
            left = 20mm,                                      % Left margin
            right = 20mm]{geometry}                           % Right margin

\usepackage{cmbright}                                         % SS font - Comment this line for LaTeX base font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}                      % comment to revert to Comptuter Modern
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                   % Includes letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                      % 8-bit encoding with 256 glyphs
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black]{hyperref}       % Hyper-references in PDF (e.g. urlcolor=blue)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                         % Headers and footers
\usepackage[english]{babel}                                   % Babel and language definitions
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}                % Include appendixes
\usepackage{lipsum}                                           % Generate automatic text - Lorem Ipsum
\usepackage{caption}                                          % Manage captions in floats
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\usepackage{titlesec} % for customizing chapter titles
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for customizing header/footer

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % chapter name in the left of header
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % page number in the center of footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} % add a line under the header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the line under the footer

\captionsetup[table]{skip=6pt}                                % Gap between captions and tables
\graphicspath{{Images/}}                                      % Path to folder where pictures are stored

\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\theAuthor}                                 % Footer left-odd and right-even: author name

\begin{document}                                              % Start document


% -------------------------------------------------------------
% LINE UNDER CHAPTER TITLES ON EVERY PAGE
% -------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{50\p@}\hrule\vspace{5pt}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{50\p@}\hrule\vspace{5pt}}{}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\textit{Interim Report}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\makeatother

% -------------------------------------------------------------
% ARABIC PAGE NUMBERS
% -------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % chapter name in the left of header
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % page number in the center of footer
    \fancyhead[R]{\textit{Interim Report}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} % add a line under the header
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the line under the footer
}

% -------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapters
% -------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1-2] \cite{example-citation}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Images/simply-supported-beam.png}
    \caption{Enter Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\listoffigures                                                % Add list of figures

\end{document}
```

With the following references.bib file

```
 @misc{example-citation, 
    title={Quadcopter Dynamics},
    url={https://uk.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/parrot/ug/quadcopter-dynamics.html},
    journal={Quadcopter Dynamics - MATLAB &amp; Simulink - MathWorks United Kingdom}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm afraid we will only be able to help you efficiently if you can share an example document with us that reproduces the issue you are asking about with as little code as possible. This is not just about the bibliography. It is also about your sectioning setup. Please share an MWE with us: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

Comment: Best guess: you're using a page style with headers even on the first page of chapters. You've adapted the title produced by `\chapter{}` but not that produced by some other command, such as `\chapter*{}` or `\appendix{}` or you're using multiple chapter styles. Basically, the problem is due to code you've not shown.

Comment: I've included a MWE, hopefully thats up to the standards provided from the link you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following right before `printbibliography` resolved the issue I face

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{30pt}

\printbibliography

\listoffigures
```

However, the thing that I am still trying to understand is why is it that the chapter works just fine but when it comes to bibliography, it just wouldnt work and requires different configuration